# Count property based on specifics conditions in Power BI/ Power Query

Tags: excel, count, powerbi

**- edit with more examples -**

I´m having a issue with counting because it´s very specific and accordingly to the filter used.

I´m counting species and I have two situations:

1. when the species is identified (ex. Alouatta guariba)
2. when the species is identified only to the genus (ex. Alouatta sp.)

So, I have a dataset similar to this:

```
 Local  Species                 Date
1  A    Akodon montensis        22/08/2019
2  A    Alouatta guariba        22/08/2019
3  A    Cabassous tatouay       22/08/2019
4  B    Cavia aperea            22/08/2019
5  C    Coendou spinosus        23/08/2019
6  G    Conepatus chinga        24/08/2019
7  B    Cuniculus paca          25/08/2019
8  B    Alouatta sp.            26/08/2019
```

(*1st ex*) In this case, I consider a total of **7** species, because there is a identified species (Alouatta guariba) for the uncertain (Alouatta sp.) and I´m beeing conservative. So here, I´m just not counting the "sp." species.

However, when I aplly a filter for **local B**, I would have the following list:

```
     Local  Species             Date
   1   B    Cavia aperea        22/08/2019
   2   B    Cuniculus paca      25/08/2019
   3   B    Alouatta sp.        26/08/2019
```

(*2nd ex*) In this case, I have a total of **3** species, because there´s only one of the genus "Alouatta" and I´m sure it´s a different animal from the others. In here, I **am** counting the "sp." species.

So, the problem I´m having is due to count or not to count the "sp." species, depending on the filter used and also considering my dataset is more than 100.000 rows and there´s a lot of filters.

I did it the following way in excel (using dynamic table and slicers):

```
Local  Genus (F)      Epithet (G)       Date
  A    Akodon         montensis         22/08/2019
  A    Alouatta       guariba           22/08/2019
  A    Cabassous      tatouay           22/08/2019
  B    Cavia          aperea            22/08/2019
  C    Coendou        spinosus          23/08/2019
  G    Conepatus      chinga            24/08/2019
  B    Cuniculus      paca              25/08/2019
  B    Alouatta       sp.               26/08/2019
```

> for each row **in the dynamic table** `=IF(AND(G1="sp.";COUNTIF(F:F;F1)>1);"0";"1")`

ie. when my epithet is the same as "sp.", count if there´s is more than one of that genus, then reply 0 for yes (*1st ex*) and 1 for no (*2nd ex*).

Then, **my total of species** is the **sum** of those numbers.

In this case, my data range spacially move with the dynamic table and the slicers. But this way is easier to count and feels like "cheating".

Anyhow, I really have no ideia how to do it in Power BI, I would like some insight, formula ou pathway to just give me a number (total of species) in a Power BI card.

Any ideias?

Comment: You can use `SUMX` to iterate through all rows and apply your logic to count selected row or not.

Comment: Please post an example of your input data and expected results, its really hard to follow your description.

Comment: @MikeHoney Done :)

Answer (score 0):

IF and AND Excel formulas have exact matches when writing Power BI Calculated Columns. Right-click the table and choose **New column** or from the **Modeling** ribbon choose **New column**.

An equivalent for COUNTIF is a CALCULATE - COUNTROWS - FILTER - EARLIEST pattern.

- CALCULATE - breaks out of the current row context so you can query other rows and modify the filters
- COUNTROWS - counts rows returned
- FILTER - returns a filtered table - in your case all rows with a matching genus
- EARLIEST - returns a value from the current row (before the CALCULATE kicked in)

Here's an example that should match your COUNTIF (assuming your table name is Table):

`CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( 'Table' ) , FILTER( 'Table' , 'Table'[genus] = EARLIEST( 'Table'[genus] ) ) )`